# Не правильно работает метод substr()

Tags: javascript

При попытке обработать значение взятое из объекта и имеющего тип строки, функция substr() работает не корректно. В чем может быть проблема?

```
var formula = self.eqstat.formula;
var formula2 = "string";

console.log(formula)
```

> "formula"

```
var left = formula.toString().substr(0,4);
var left2 = formula2.substr(0,4);

console.log(left,left2);
```

> [obj stri

Answer (score 0):

Значение получалось из объекта text 
Вот так - self.eqstat.formula = document.getSelection().anchorNode

Сделал вот так - self.eqstat.formula = document.getSelection().anchorNode.nodeValue;